# USDT tokens accidentally sent to off-curve SPL token account

Tags: transaction, token-account

I sent some USDT-SPL from Huobi (HTX) directly to my main Solana address.
DXu4QfQa3LdVp6ZTw1u7odR1rV95rUiR8XWtUw2yCWv8

This seems to have invoked a program to create a USDT-SPL token account, which is owned by the main Solana account.
GoLQ6WEKR4kvbGGwG3uC1HKpsWWuR8WzYfWz2iJp18kx

This newly created token account now shows as $0 USDT balance and $325 USDT holdings, and owns another token account which shows as $325 USDT balance and $0 USDT holdings.
Ddd4eKySysqfS9d8ix7BDxs8CXrm8puVbRqVF9gtaydA

Looking at my other token accounts I see that the difference is that they are associated accounts (where this one is non-associated) and they do not further contain other accounts, but contain tokens.

When I look at my wallet, I see that the supposedly non-associated account always appear as my default USDT-SPL token address, so why is it non-associated I still do not understand.

Two questions - is it possible to move the tokens from the third layer account, to the USDT-SPL account? And is it possible to make it an associated account?

In other words - are these USDT tokens stuck or can they be obtained somehow?

Answer (score 1):

This should count as a nested account (token account owned by a token account, assuming it also covers non ATAs). You should be able to either create a recover nested instruction, see:

https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/master/associated-token-account/program/src/instruction.rs

or use this (assuming it works, I haven't tested it beyond connecting and attempting to find nested accounts):

https://tools.blastctrl.com/spl-token-tools/recover-nested

As I understand, the instruction aims to send any tokens held in the nested account up one level to the parent account.

Comment: Hey, thanks for linking that tool. I did give it a try but it seems to be unable to find a nested account, but I think that may be because it scans through the ATAs only. In this case, my token account appears as non-associated. Any idea if that's possible to access?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and found a workaround using Solflare:

1. send assets which are in the associated token account (the ones you can use) to a new wallet
2. burn&close the associated account which is now on 0
3. send assets from the nested account to yourself also using solflare

After this it will create a new associated token account which is offCurve in the explorer and you will be able to use the assets

Comment: I think I made it worse. I USDT-SPL non-associated account where the nested account was, along with the tokens in the nested account. Now I have a new USDT-SPL account which appears to be associated, but has nothing in it.

Comment: try to go to raydium.io/debug and it might let you migrate your old token accounts to associated and see if that gets you anywhere

Answer (score 1):

raydium.io/debug works as well. You can delete an associated USDT-SLP account with nothing in it and the other one with assets should become associated.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).